# Docker: jenkins-plugin-manager gives: No argument is allowed: ???-plugin-file

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-plugins

The story: I had a fully functional Docker Jenkins image with casc working beautifully. Left it alone for half a year and now the image is gone from DockerHub. I've tried a few other Jenkins images but just can't get the casc part to work.

As I don't understand what is baked into these images, I decided to build a Jenkins image from scratch with all the pieces so that I understand and control each step. As I have mentioned, my previous image ran totally fine the main difference was that it used the legacy **jenkins-plugin-cli.sh** which is no longer available in images.

I found this page: https://medium.com/@nabujjal/build-docker-image-for-jenkins-with-centos-as-the-base-image-ad78ebba7251 and also supporting page: https://github.com/jenkinsci/plugin-installation-manager-tool/blob/master/README.md#plugin-input-format. FYI I have also tried with the 2.10.0 version in the former page listed.

I can't get past this error:

> => ERROR [10/12] RUN java -jar /tmp/jenkins-plugin-manager-2.12.9.jar --war /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war —-plugin-file /root/.jenkins/plugins/plugins.txt
>
> #14 0.266 No argument is allowed: ???-plugin-file
> #14 0.266 Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to read command-line arguments
> #14 0.266       at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.cli.Main.main(Main.java:26)
> #14 0.266 Caused by: org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineException: No argument is allowed: ???-plugin-file
> #14 0.266       at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.parseArgument(CmdLineParser.java:509)
> #14 0.266       at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.cli.Main.main(Main.java:22)

**My Dockerfile is:**

```
FROM centos:7
RUN yum install epel-release -y
RUN yum install fontconfig java-11-openjdk -y
RUN yum install wget -y
RUN wget --no-check-certificate -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo
RUN rpm -import http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key
#RUN yum install jenkins -y
RUN wget --no-check-certificate https://get.jenkins.io/war-stable/2.375.2/jenkins.war -P /usr/lib/jenkins
RUN wget https://github.com/jenkinsci/plugin-installation-manager-tool/releases/download/2.12.9/jenkins-plugin-manager-2.12.9.jar -P /tmp
COPY plugins.txt /root/.jenkins/plugins/
RUN java -jar /tmp/jenkins-plugin-manager-2.12.9.jar --war /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war —-plugin-file /root/.jenkins/plugins/plugins.txt
RUN yum clean all
COPY casc.yaml /usr/local/jenkins-casc.yaml
ENV CASC_JENKINS_CONFIG /usr/local/jenkins-casc.yaml
CMD java -Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war
```

**The full output:**

```
% docker build -t centos7 . && docker run --name centos7 --rm -p 8080:8080 centos7
[+] Building 4.5s (14/16)                                                                                                                                                                                         
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.00kB                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/centos:7                                                                                                                                                  0.6s
 => [ 1/12] FROM docker.io/library/centos:7@sha256:be65f488b7764ad3638f236b7b515b3678369a5124c47b8d32916d6487418ea4                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 62B                                                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/12] RUN yum install epel-release -y                                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/12] RUN yum install fontconfig java-11-openjdk -y                                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [ 4/12] RUN yum install wget -y                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [ 5/12] RUN wget --no-check-certificate -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [ 6/12] RUN rpm -import http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [ 7/12] RUN wget --no-check-certificate https://get.jenkins.io/war-stable/2.375.2/jenkins.war -P /usr/lib/jenkins                                                                                 0.0s
 => [ 8/12] RUN wget https://github.com/jenkinsci/plugin-installation-manager-tool/releases/download/2.12.9/jenkins-plugin-manager-2.12.9.jar -P /tmp                                                        3.6s
 => [ 9/12] COPY plugins.txt /root/.jenkins/plugins/                                                                                                                                                         0.0s 
 => ERROR [10/12] RUN java -jar /tmp/jenkins-plugin-manager-2.12.9.jar --war /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war —-plugin-file /root/.jenkins/plugins/plugins.txt                                                   0.3s 
------                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 > [10/12] RUN java -jar /tmp/jenkins-plugin-manager-2.12.9.jar --war /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war —-plugin-file /root/.jenkins/plugins/plugins.txt:                                                              
#14 0.266  --available-updates                         : Show available plugin updates for the requested plugins (default: false)
#14 0.266  --clean-download-directory                  : If sets, cleans the plugin download directory before plugin installation. Otherwise the tool performs
#14 0.266                                                plugin download and reports compatibility issues, if any. (default: false)
#14 0.266  --credentials <CREDENTIALS,CREDENTIALS,...> : Comma-separated list of credentials in format '<host>[:port]:<username>:<password>'. The password must
#14 0.266                                                not contain space or ','
#14 0.266  --jenkins-experimental-update-center URL    : Sets experimental update center; will override JENKINS_UC_EXPERIMENTAL environment variable. If not
#14 0.266                                                set via CLI option or environment variable, will default to https://updates.jenkins.io/experimental/upd
#14 0.266                                                ate-center.json
#14 0.266  --jenkins-incrementals-repo-mirror URL      : Set Maven mirror to be used to download plugins from the Incrementals repository, will override the
#14 0.266                                                JENKINS_INCREMENTALS_REPO_MIRROR environment variable. If not set via CLI option or environment
#14 0.266                                                variable, will default to https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/incrementals
#14 0.266  --jenkins-plugin-info URL                   : Sets the location of plugin information; will override JENKINS_PLUGIN_INFO environment variable. If
#14 0.266                                                not set via CLI option or environment variable, will default to
#14 0.266                                                https://updates.jenkins.io/plugin-versions.json
#14 0.266  --jenkins-update-center URL                 : Sets main update center; will override JENKINS_UC environment variable. If not set via CLI option or
#14 0.266                                                environment variable, will default to https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json
#14 0.266  --jenkins-version                           : Jenkins version to be used. If undefined, Plugin Manager will use alternative ways to retrieve the
#14 0.266                                                version, e.g. from WAR
#14 0.266  --latest VALUE                              : Set to true to download the latest version of all dependencies, even if the version(s) of the
#14 0.266                                                requested plugin(s) are not the latest. By default, plugin dependency versions will be determined by
#14 0.266                                                the update center metadata or plugin MANIFEST.MF (default: true)
#14 0.266  --latest-specified                          : Download latest transitive dependencies of any plugin that is requested to have the latest version. By
#14 0.266                                                default, plugin dependency versions will be determined by the update center metadata or plugin
#14 0.266                                                MANIFEST.MF (default: false)
#14 0.266  --list (-l)                                 : Lists all plugins currently installed and if given a list of plugins to install either via file or CLI
#14 0.266                                                option, all plugins that will be installed by the tool (default: false)
#14 0.266  --no-download                               : Avoid downloading plugins; can be used in combination with other options to see information about
#14 0.266                                                plugins and their dependencies (default: false)
#14 0.266  --output (-o) [STDOUT | YAML | TXT]         : Output format for available updates (default: STDOUT)
#14 0.266  --plugin-download-directory (-d) FILE       : Path to directory in which to install plugins; will override PLUGIN_DIR environment variable.
#14 0.266  --plugin-file (-f) FILE                     : Path to plugins.txt or plugins.yaml file
#14 0.266  --plugins (-p) STRING[]                     : List of plugins to install, separated by a space
#14 0.266  --skip-failed-plugins                       : Skip installing plugins that have failed to download. By default, if a single plugin is unavailable
#14 0.266                                                then all plugins fail to download and install. (default: false)
#14 0.266  --verbose                                   : Verbose logging (default: false)
#14 0.266  --version (-v)                              : View version and exit (default: false)
#14 0.266  --view-all-security-warnings                : Set to true to show all plugins that have security warnings (default: false)
#14 0.266  --view-security-warnings                    : Show if any security warnings exist for the requested plugins (default: false)
#14 0.266  --war (-w) VAL                              : Path to Jenkins war file (default: /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war)
#14 0.266 No argument is allowed: ???-plugin-file
#14 0.266 Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to read command-line arguments
#14 0.266       at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.cli.Main.main(Main.java:26)
#14 0.266 Caused by: org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineException: No argument is allowed: ???-plugin-file
#14 0.266       at org.kohsuke.args4j.CmdLineParser.parseArgument(CmdLineParser.java:509)
#14 0.266       at io.jenkins.tools.pluginmanager.cli.Main.main(Main.java:22)
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c java -jar /tmp/jenkins-plugin-manager-2.12.9.jar --war /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war —-plugin-file /root/.jenkins/plugins/plugins.txt]: exit code: 1
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

The flags you're passing to "plugin manager" seems to be causing the problem. You should delete the dashes from the flags and retype them. This problem was likely caused by copying and pasting from Medium.

```
java -jar /tmp/jenkins-plugin-manager-2.12.9.jar --war /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --plugin-file /root/.jenkins/plugins/plugins.txt
```